# Trying to reset the console input stream

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that loops until a key is press, and then ask the user if he wants to quit.  Right now after the computer ask the user if he wants to quit, the computer exits and does not wait for the user to type in exit.

It seems reader.readLine()  returns the charters the user previously types in.

I tried to do the following to FLUSH the old data from the input stream.
 reader.mark(0);
 reader.reset();

The program still has the same behavior.
code
} while(System.in.available()==0);  // loop until a key is press

```
     System.out.println("type exit to quit" );  // tell the user to type exit if he she wants to exit   

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     // get rid of old data in input stream, not working
     reader.mark(0);
     reader.reset();    

     // get input from  user     
     mEnd=reader.readLine();    
} while(mEnd.compareTo("exit")!=0);
```

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood but why can't you simply use the `read()` method from the BufferedReader and check the value against the exit character. No need to mark or reset the stream in any way.

Comment: You don't say what exacyly you mean by 'reset the console input stream', but `mark()` and `reset()` do not 'get rid of old data'. They let you read it multiple times. Question remains obscure.

Comment: If you want to match more than one character, simply remove the mark/reset statements. Perhaps also change the `compareTo()` to a `equals()` or a `equalsIgnoreCase()` for readability.

Comment: Sorry for not explaing my issue more clearly, I'm trying to flush the input stream, so readline will only get the new data

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is not structured correctly in context of the rest of the program. The while loop has to wrap the code you want to continue to be executed until the user types `quit`. I'm not sure why your code uses `reader.mark(0);` and `reader.reset();` because this can be accomplished by doing this:

Consider this code sample:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!input.hasNext("quit")) {

    String expression = input.nextLine(); // gets the next line from the Scanner

    // process the input

}

// once the value "quit" has been entered, the while loop terminates
```

Is this what you are intending to accomplish?